# Delphi using Gnostice eDocEngine , PDF toolkit create and alter PDF

Tags: delphi, pdf, delphi-xe, gnostice-pdf-one

I am using Delphi XE6 and using Gnostice eDocEngine to create the PDF and Gnostice PDF toolkit to edit/ alter PDF.
I am able to create a PDF using eDocEngine and also able to view the created PDF using PDFviewer.

I have a few queries:

1.When creating a PDF if along with the text I need to add form fills like the checkbox, drop-down box then it is possible to add at runtime? Something like drag-drop component and save is available?

2.When we load the PDF into PDFviewer, how can we edit on click of the PDF?

Cany anyone assist me on this?

Comment: Those are often called **PDF Forms** and searching on that in general or in the help should get you started.

Comment: @Brian using the gtPDFViewer i am able to view the PDF.However, I am unable to edit this PDF.Can you assist me on how to edit the PDF  that is loaded in PDFViewer?

Comment: Start with the help. ex https://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=146&t=PDF_Processing_with_Gnostice_PDFtoolkit_Part_1 (bit old but don't see a newer one and likely not much has changed).